# Deep clone class and subclasses in C#

Tags: c#, class, clone

I recently discovered that MemberwiseCloning a class doesn't seem to clone it's subclasses (classes defined within it). They still seem to be treated as pointers. Is there some way I can clone a whole class with all subclasses?

Comment: " Is there some way I can clone a whole class with all subclasses?" - Yes. Write a clone Method. Search the internet to find the short code snippet that uses serialization. Maybe try typing your title into a serach engine?

Comment: There is a holo tickbox next to each answer, it gives you a couple of points by ticking it and saves everyone's time by letting them know your question is solved. Good luck:)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this

```
public object Clone()
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(
           null, 
           new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone));
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memStream, this);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about performance ?! Should we use this trick or defining the function ICloeable.Clone() for each sub class to gain performance ?

Comment: @K4timini: if you need a deep clone, I think this is the most performant method.